# Is it safe to publish a person's genome?

Tags: genetics, human-genome

I recently went through the process of having my genome analyzed by 23andme, and received my raw data.

Its very interesting to me, and I want to share it with the world.

Is it safe to publish the raw genome to a public site, or are there reasons I should keep this information private?

What could someone do with the raw genome of another person? Outside of privacy concerns, is there any potential for malicious concerns from someone with this information?

Comment: This is how the clone wars begin.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Here, we only deal with Biology question, not with questions of personal safety, information security, future political decision or justice. Your question touches all these fields and it is hard to imagine what SE site would be welcoming your question. Maybe [informationSecurity.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1. I would assume that this question is off-topic on Biology.SE, but I am unsure. 2. It's not a 'raw genome'. It's information based on an extremely limited number of ascertained variable sites, referred to as SNP genotypes. 3. The fact that you ask this very question should make you not give away the data. If I were you, I would - if I wanted to tell people about it - give away the major findings (e.g. ancestry estimates) without giving away actual variant data.

Comment: @Kritner I am not willing to go into a star wars argument, but I don't think the clone wars have anything to do with making genetic data public or not :)

Comment: I believe this topic is on-topic for Biology.SE due to the specific knowledge required to understand the implications of my question. Other sites not filled with experts in the topic may mis-inform me

Comment: @AndrewDiamond The fact that it takes some knowledge in science and economy to discuss whether a country should build a new nuclear reactor does not make the discussion of the decision purely scientific or economic. It remains within the field of politics. You can ask us specific question that are purely scientific that will eventually help you take your decision though.

Comment: There is some debate, about which I'm not very familiar, over whether or not health insurance companies should have access to such information. If the data reveals a genetic disease, it could be the basis to reject coverage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as safe as to publish your fingerprints. Right now, there is little that anyone can do with your genetic information but in the future, this will change.

One of the feared consequences it concerns what companies may do with that information. Can it be used against you? In some cases, it may.

For example, if you have a predisposition for a genetic disease, then an insurance company may find a way to refuse to insure you. As far I know, right now this is illegal, but you never know.